Error While Loading Package "MatrixModels" in Cran R on Debian 12
I have been trying to load the R Package "MatrixModels". My OS is Debian 12. I am getting the following error -
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : namespace ‘Matrix’ 1.5-3 is being loaded,
but >= 1.6.0 is required Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom
-> asNamespace -> loadNamespace Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘MatrixModels’ * removing
‘/home/parthasarathighose/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/MatrixModels’ 
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘MatrixModels’ had non-zero exit status

How can I address this error and load the package "MatrixModels"?
Your support will be helpful.
Regards and best,
Partha

Package Matrix is a base package and if you have version 1.5-3 installed, then it's time to update R. (In R 4.4.1, packageVersion('Matrix') returns ‘1.6.5’). Alternativey, settle for an archived version of the package you are trying to install, MatrixModels.
